# Не могу понять почему не работает условие в скрипте.

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, не могу понять почему не срабатывает условие в while.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var arr = [], i = 0;

do {
  var number = +prompt('Введите элемент массива - ' + (i + 1), '');
  arr[i] = number;
  i++;
} while((number != null) || (number != '') || (number != NaN));
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
  sum += arr[i]; 
}

alert(sum);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вам надо делать условие **И** (повторять пока number **и** не null не '' **и** не isNaN)

```
var arr = [], i = 0,sum;

do {
  var number = +prompt('Введите элемент массива - ' + (i + 1), '');
  arr[i] = number;
  i++;
} while((number !== null) && (number !== '') && (number !== NaN));

for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length + 1; i++) {
  sum += arr[i]; 
}
```

но вообще лучше заменить это условие на isNaN(number) предварительно приведя number к float:

```
var arr = [], i = 0,sum;

do {
  var number = parseFloat(prompt('Введите элемент массива - ' + (i + 1), ''));
  arr[i] = number;
  i++;
} while(!isNaN(number));

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
  sum += arr[i]; 
}
```

вообще, чтобы избегнуть присвоения элементу массива нечислового значения в таком перевернутом цикле, вам надо сделать вот такой выверт:

```
var arr = [], i = 0,sum=0;

do {
  var number = parseFloat(prompt('Введите элемент массива - ' + (i + 1), ''));

} while(!isNaN(number) && ((arr[i]=number) || true) && ((i++)||true));
console.log(arr);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
  sum += arr[i]; 
  console.log(sum);
}
alert(sum);
```

cобственно поэтому я и не люблю do {} while() конструкции, гораздо проще сделать так:

```
var arr = [],sum=0;

while (true) {
    var number = parseFloat(prompt('Введите элемент массива - ' + arr.length, ''));
    if (!isNaN(number)) arr.push(number);
       else break;
}
var l=arr.length;
while (l--) sum+=arr[l];
alert(sum);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/e4RzW/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, просто не могу понять по логике, должны выполнятся сразу три условия, то есть число должно быть не null, не NaN ?

Comment: а строкой типа "СТРОКА" оно может быть ?

Comment: спасибо, дошло)

Comment: вот ещё так можно извратиться, типа короче но не понятнее http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/e4RzW/5/